# How can I render a canvas with WebGL enabled on an Ubuntu server?

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, webgl

I have a program that uses [devtool](https://github.com/hadley/devtools) to run a headless browser that renders a canvas element, converts it to a base64 image, then saves it to disk.  I'd like to have this run on an aws G2 Ubuntu server, which has NVIDIA graphics cards.

To run the program, I use `xvfb` for a virtual frame buffer.  The command looks like this:

```
xvfb-run --server-args="-screen 0 1024x768x24" devtool main.js -i index.html -h -c
```

The problem I'm having is with WebGL support.  Under the hood, devtool uses [electron](http://electron.atom.io/) to create a browser context.  On my OSX machine, this works fine.  But on the server, it gives me a couple errors:

```
Xlib:  extension "RANDR" missing on display ":9.0"
```

and

```
[5331:0127/180654:ERROR:sandbox_linux.cc(338)] InitializeSandbox() called with multiple threads in process gpu-process
```

I've troubleshooted in a number of ways.  For RANDR, I've tried enabling it with `+extension RANDR` with devtool.

I attempted enabling the `experimentalFeatures` flag for electron (within devtool source code) with WebGL support.  The features I tried were `disable-gpu`, `disable-gpu-sandbox`, and `ignore-gpu-blacklist`.

Any help would be very much appreciated, or if you have a better idea to do what I'm doing, I'd love to hear it!